# How do I use the sort method so I can read the last email in my outlook folder?

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am trying to create a python code that will read the subject of the most recent email in every folder of my outlook account.

I am able to open my email account and loop through every folder in it, however I cannot open my most recent email.

I looked at similar questions and tried using the `get.Last()` method. To use this method I understand that I have to sort my emails but I don't think that I am using the `.sort` method correctly because it is causing new errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/myname/OneDrive/Documents/Computer Science/Email reader/project.py", line 24, in <module>
    checksubj = messages.Subject
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Subject'
```

Here is my code:

```
import win32com.client
import win32com
import os
import sys

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

folder = outlook.Folders.Item(3)
print(folder.Name)

for subfolder in folder.Folders:
    print(subfolder.Name)
    messages = subfolder.Items
    messages.sort
    messages = messages.GetLast()
    checksubj = messages.Subject
    checksend = messages.Sender
    if "Success" in checksubj:
        print(str(checksend)+" Success")
    elif "Failure" in checksubj:
        print(str(checksend)+" Failure")
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like it's being caused by sort. I would consider going at this with a debugger it will teach you how to debug :D.

Here is an idication of things you need to check:

1. does .sort exist, if so what does it return
   solution:
   print(messages.sort) -> will let you know what this returns, (a function, a list etc...)
   quick: dir(messages) will show what methods/variables etc are available.
2. what is messages
   if it's a list can you just call sort(messages) or something like that...
3. read the api you are using. (more thorough) but harder.

For future reference:
Please be careful when posting content like this because it is difficult to give you anything useful unless either someone who has done exactly what you are trying to do has seen your question (which is unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

The [Items.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort) method takes two parameters and sorts the collection of items by the specified property. The index for the collection is reset to 1 upon completion of this method. For example, in VBA the code may look like that:

```
Sub SortByDueDate() 
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.TaskItem 
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items 
 
 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks) 
 Set myItems = myFolder.Items 
 myItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False 
 For Each myItem In myItems 
 MsgBox myItem.Subject & "-- " & myItem.DueDate 
 Next myItem 
End Sub
```

Most probably you will have to sort items depending on the [ReceivedTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.receivedtime) property which returns a Date indicating the date and time at which the item was received.